# Output filtering from nodejs while getting data from mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have an JSON like `{'a':'b', 'c':{'e':[{}],'f':[{}]}}` I want to query this structure such that i should get only `{'a':'b', 'c':{'e':[{}]}}` as output. To achieve this i am trying to follow below options mechanism but not able to get the desired output.

```
var options = {_id:0,'a':1,'c'.'e':1};
```

How can this be resolved? Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.

Just do like this.

`var options = {_id:0,'a':1,'c.e':1};`

Im not sure what driver you using, but if you use mongodb native driver http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/ this is the example.

```
collection.find({}).project(options).toArray(function(err, data){
   //data will contain desired fields.
})
```

Hope this helps.